# Kafka: Write custom partitioner or just use Key?

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, kafka-producer-api

So I have a Kafka topic with multiple partitions and on it I'm producing messages. I want my messages to be partitioned based on user id. I can achieve this either by using UserId as the message key or by writing a custom partitioner. How do I figure out which is the right solution, what are the pros and cons?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking. Please add details or clarify the question so that an intelligent response can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know using user-id as the key, you are sure that messages with same user-id will be delivered always to the same partition but you can't decide the partition itself. I mean that the default partitioner process an hash on the key % number of partitions for having the destination partition.
If in your application you need that messages with a specific user-id go to a specific partition (i.e. you want that user-id beginning with "A" go to partition 0) you need to write a custom partitioner.
If you have no restrictions I think that the default partitioner using user-id as key works fine for you.
In any case after sending and on receiving you got information about the partition.

Comment: So a custom partitioner is more for making sure messages end up in a specific partition rather than making sure messages end up in the same partition?
Do you happen to have a use case for when I want to control which specific partition a message ends up in?

Comment: Yes. You can do the partitioner in that way because you are writing it so it means that you have to write the logic for defining the destination partition.